# Why my CodeRunner mac app keep output “(B[m” before my correct output?

Tags: ruby

When I code test ruby script, it keeps output **"(B[m"** before my other output, even thought I just have single line `puts` statement.

Just as follow:

[image]

See the **"(B[m"** before my output text "      test". It's really annoying me for a long while. Any help will be preciated!

---

**Update:**

It occurs at CodeRunner version 1.3.1, and in latest version(2.2.1) I also get a "(B" there!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a language encoding issue.  Check that the space characters at the beginning of the string are actually half-width space, and not Japanese full-width spaces.